# Cant sort html table using sorttable.js

Tags: javascript, html, pug, sorttable.js

Im having trouble trying to sort a dynamically created html table. I create it using jade/pug. I am trying to use the sorttable.js script found here http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/ . I am still kind of new to html/javascript. So if there is some obvious reason why its not working could someone point it out please?

Here is some of the html code generated from the template

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script src="/path/to/sorttable.js"></script>
   <style>
    th.clickable:hover
    {
     color:green
    }    
    th, td
    {
     padding:5px;
    }
    th.clickable
    {
     cursor: pointer;    
    }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <script>
  var newTableObject = document.getElementById(tbl)
  sorttable.makeSortable(newTableObject)
 </script>
 <table class="sortable" id="tbl">
  <tr>
   <th class="clickable">id</th>
   <th class="clickable">value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>100</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>200</td>
 </tr> 
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The goal is to have it so when I click on the header it sorts the table by that column.

Answer (score 1):

Please excuse if this is already known...but
The script tag gets read and executed whenever the browser comes across it. Have you tried putting the script tag after your table?

Answer (score 0):

At the time your code executes:

```
var newTableObject = document.getElementById(tbl)
sorttable.makeSortable(newTableObject)
```

Your table hasn't rendered yet and is unavailable.  So you;re passing `undefined` to the `sorttable.makeSortable` method.  You can test this by adding a trace statement after you get the element:

```
var newTableObject = document.getElementById(tbl)
console.log(newTableObject)
```

You should wait to fire this code after your table has rendered.  Something like this:

```
onLoad = function(){
    var newTableObject = document.getElementById(tbl)
    sorttable.makeSortable(newTableObject)
}
```

and declare that like so:

```
// using jQ
$(document).ready( onLoad())
```

or for plain JS

```
<body onload="onload()">
```

Comment: or you can try moving your script block below your declared table, though that is not the best, most obvious solution.

Comment: works for me (that is the onload being called and table not being undefined) http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/pbKymd

Comment: in that example, when you click on id and value it sorts (and reverse sorts) them both?

Comment: also tested it here in jsbin as that would show a more realistic example https://jsbin.com/febawuqoto/edit?html,output

Comment: I didn't wire up sortable, only wired up the part where you have to defer the onload logic once the UI has indeed loaded.  You'll still need to wire up sortable.

Comment: strangely I define onLoad = function(){ ....} in my header script tag. then I do <body onload='onLoad()'> and it says that onLoad is undefined?